# Using boost/regex with Rcpp

Tags: r, boost, rcpp

I am trying to compile my boost/regrex-based library function in R.  This is my example code:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp;  
using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

string jphtest(string);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
string jphtest(string src) {

        return(regex_replace(src, regex("ABC"), "123"));
}
```

When I attempt to test this with R CMD check, it doesn't work.  Here's the error I get:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Users/howardjp/Documents/Research/foniks/..Rcheck/foniks/libs/foniks.so':   
dlopen(/Users/howardjp/Documents/Research/foniks/..Rcheck/foniks/libs/foniks.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9do_assignEPKcS7_j
  Referenced from: /Users/howardjp/Documents/Research/foniks/..Rcheck/foniks/libs/foniks.so
  Expected in: flat namespace in /Users/howardjp/Documents/Research/foniks/..Rcheck/foniks/libs/foniks.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

Any help on how to correct this is appreciated.

Comment: See http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/boost-regular-expressions/

Comment: I am not sure how that's relevant.  The example compiles, loads, and executes via Rcpp::sourceCpp.  However, if I run check on the package it's in, there's a dynamic link error on load.

Comment: @JamesHoward It's a good question and informative discussion, would you mind updating your initial post with the solution you decided to use at the end. I'm facing the same problem and thinking what would be the best way to address it; working solution would be informative.

Comment: @Konrad, I gave up and did it in R. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BH](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/bh.html) package *very conveniently* packages a large part of Boost in a header-only library you can simply use in R via `LinkingTo:` or our plugin.

However, there are parts of Boost for which you need to *link as well* and regex is one them. Filesystem, threads, program_options, ... are other examples.  You can do that either in a package, or via *an explicit linking instruction* as i do in the [Rcpp Gallery article](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/boost-regular-expressions/) that Gabor already pointed too. Note that that solution is not entirely portable; you would need a package to link to the right file extension on Windows, OS X, Linux etc.

In short, your dismissal of Gabor's comment is wrong as you seem to have overlooked that Boost Regex is not header-only.

Comment: Well, that article is missing one critical piece of information,  then.  In what file do I place the Sys.setenv call?

Comment: The Rcpp Gallery is processed by knitr which executes the R pieces, some which happen to pull in C++ pieces via Rcpp. You can set the environment *whereever* you want; it simply has to be set before `R CMD ...` is called so that it takes effect.  So in the article we do it from R; on my own system I might use `~/.profile` or something. Makes sense?  What you **really** want is small package where you use `src/Makevars` for this.

Comment: Of course it makes sense, but it doesn't work to define the variable on a system specific basis if I want to make a distributable package.  So when I place the variable into src/Makevars, I get that the library cannot be found, "ld: library not found for -lboost_regex"

Comment: I posted something with an error, and we got out of order.  Sorry.

Comment: That is a different problem. See Writing R Extensions; many of us use configure.

Comment: Got it.  I just needed to know I was trying to do the impossible.  Now to figure out configure!

Comment: Come to rcpp-devel and I'll help. There are existing snippets you can use; I have configure scripts (from pre-BH) that look for Boost, but currently none for boost regex.